# How can i change the hyperlink from the sign request mail in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

When we initiate the docusign request, signing email willl trigger to signer email id, from that email, we will get document review URL, so i need to change as my app URL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. You can send your own emails with links to your app but DocuSign won't send emails to apps developed by third parties.

Now if you want a hybrid embedded/remote signing where emails are sent and your app is still used for embedded signing - you can do that.

Comment: Thank you, i can use the embeded concept, i have done also and got the sign URL, but getting below issue while adding in iframe in html in out page.                                                                             "Refused to display 'https://account-d.docusign.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Comment: Refused to display 'https://account-d.docusign.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.      :===> Please suggest here to load signing URL in webpage

Comment: you cannot use an iframe for showing the login UI. Just use a new window instead.